# How to disable gzip compression with wget?

Tags: wget, gzip, mirror

There are other [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15176/using-wget-what-is-the-right-command-to-get-gzipped-version-instead-of-the-actu) asking how to *enable* gzip compression with wget, and lots of [web pages](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/7180/get-gzip-compressed-web-page-using-wget.) out there telling how to do this, but I need the opposite.  I'm trying to locally mirror a site, and I'm just getting the home page as a gzipped file, which in turn breaks the recursion, so I can't get the whole site.

I can gunzip that file, but that still doesn't give me a recursive download of the whole cotton-pickin' site.

How do I turn off or prevent gzipping?

***EDIT***: The exact command I issued is

```
wget --random-wait -r -p -e robots=off -U mozilla http://www.example.com --reject png,jpg,jpeg,gif  --progress=dot --wait=7
```

Comment: Also, the manpage has no mention of gzipping at all.

Comment: `wget` _does_ recursive downloading on its own, and I've never seen it to `gzip` (or otherwise pack) anything. Exactly what commands are you issuing? You might need to edit out parts of the URL for privacy, edit that into the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

D'oh!  I figured it out.  I had put

```
header = Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

in my `~/.wgetrc` some time ago, assuming that it would only affect the way data was passed across the network, never thinking that wget would be unable to read the gzipped data.

In retrospect it makes sense: this is just a header that `wget` allows you to use (since it allows you to use any header that a browser might pass, or any you want to make up for that matter) rather than a switch built into `wget`, so why would anyone expect `wget` to automatically handle the gzipping?  It would certainly be nice if it did, but there's no reason to assume that it would.

Answer (score 1):

If specifying `--header='Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate'` won't work, maybe this one would:

```
wget -O- http://example.com/file.gz | gunzip -c
```

Or by using `curl` and its `libz` library which suppose to do automatic decompression of compressed files over HTTP (`curl -V | grep libz`). It has also `--compress` parameter.

Comment: This may be useful, but it isn't quite aimed at what I'm actually trying to solve with this question.  I'm trying to *disable* gzip, because it's preventing recursion.  This answer doesn't solve that.