# Wget returning binary instead of html?

Tags: wget, character-encoding, gzip, http

I am using wget to download a static html page.  The W3C Validator tells me the page is encoded in UTF-8.  Yet when I cat the file after download, I get a bunch of binary nonsense.  I'm on Ubuntu, and I thought the default encoding was UTF-8?  That's what my locale file seems to say.  Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

Also, looks like `Content-Encoding: gzip`.  Perhaps this makes a diff?

This is the simple request:

```
wget https://www.example.com/page.html
```

I also tried this:

```
wget https://www.example.com/page.html -q -O - | iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 > output.html
```

Which returned: `iconv: illegal input sequence at position 40`

cat'ing the file returns binary that looks like this:

```
l�?חu�`�q"�:)s��dġ__��~i��6n)T�$H�#���QJ
```

Result of `xxd output.html | head -20` :

```
00000000: 1f8b 0800 0000 0000 0003 bd56 518f db44  ...........VQ..D
00000010: 107e a6bf 62d4 8a1e 48b9 d8be 4268 9303  .~..b...H...Bh..
00000020: 8956 082a 155e 7a02 21dd cbd8 3bb6 97ae  .V.*.^z.!...;...
00000030: 77cd ee38 39f7 a1bf 9d19 3bb9 0bbd 9c40  w..89.....;....@
00000040: 2088 12c5 de9d 9df9 be99 6f67 f751 9699   .........og.Q..
00000050: 500d 1d79 5eee a265 faec 7151 e4ab 6205  P..y^..e..qQ..b.
00000060: 4dd3 0014 1790 e7d0 77c0 ef2f cbf8 cde3  M.......w../....
00000070: cf1f 7d6c 7d69 ec16 d0d9 c67f 7d7d 56c9  ..}l}i......}}V.
00000080: 04c5 eb33 35fc e49e 2563 e908 ca10 0d45  ...35...%c.....E
00000090: 31ce afcf a022 e77a 34c6 fa46 46be d88f  1....".z4..FF...
000000a0: a41e ab79 446d 76d6 702b cf45 9e7f ba77  ...yDmv.p+.E...w
000000b0: 7dc2 779c 274e cc18 483c 3a12 0f75 f07c  }.w.'N..H<:..u.|
000000c0: 5e63 67dd b886 ab48 e550 b5c4 f0e3 db0d  ^cg....H.P......
000000d0: 54c1 85b8 8627 2ff3 2ff3 17f9 0626 d31d  T....'/./....&..
000000e0: d9a6 e5b5 4076 663f 94ec 7b5a 17cf 7ade  ....@vf?..{Z..z.
000000f0: 00d3 0d9f 4fcc d733 ef8d a0bb 0a06 c7eb  ....O..3........
00000100: b304 6fb1 b1cc 18ed 90e0 8710 43aa 424f  ..o.........C.BO
00000110: 50c7 d0c1 2bac 09be 4d1c 2566 335e 666c  P...+...M.%f3^fl
00000120: 1e20 951d 58fd 6774 f3e9 f317 749f 7fc4  . ..X.gt....t...
00000130: d651 cdca f5a7 b0a5 aea4 08ab 055c e4c5  .Q...........\..
```

Also, strangely, the output file seems to open properly in TextWrangler!

Comment: revising the question to provide the command being used and the output being generated would be huge help here.

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 40

Comment: Can you show us what the "binary nonsense" looks like?  I'd suggest running:  `xxd  dubious.file` | head -20` and including that as an update.

Comment: @BruceEdiger updated.

Comment: Also, strangely, the output file seems to open correctly in TextWrangler!

Comment: try running `file dubious.file` and post the result.

Comment: @loa_in_ output.html: gzip compressed data, from Unix

Comment: Read: [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68117/how-to-disable-gzip-compression-with-wget) - you seem to be sending a header that suggests being able to handle gzipped data to the server.

Comment: _"I also tried this: `wget ... | iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 ...`"_ - Why would you?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) compressed file. You can find this out by running the [`file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) command, which figures out the file format from [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in the data (this is how programs such as Text Wrangler figure out that the file is compressed as well):

```
file output.html
wget -O - … | file -
```

The server (I guessed it from the content you showed) is sending gzipped data and correctly setting the header

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

but wget doesn't support that. In recent versions, wget sends `Accept-encoding: identity`, to tell the server not to compress or otherwise encode the data. In older versions, you can send the header manually:

```
wget --header 'Accept-encoding: identity' …
```

However this particular server appears to be broken: it sends compressed data even when told not to encode the data in any way. So you'll have to decompress the data manually.

```
wget -O output.html.gz … && gunzip output.html.gz
```

Comment: Very nice analysis

Comment: BTW, you can pipe into `gunzip` the same way as you do to `file`, if you don't want to store a temporary.  You might want to pass `-c` or `--to-stdout` (or call it as `zcat`) to insert it into the pipeline in the question, between `wget` and `iconv`.

Answer (score 15):

This file is still compressed with `gzip`.

You can see that the first two bytes 0x1f8b match the [`gzip` signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6059342/2344631). So to read the data you need to uncompress it.

```
mv file.dat file.dat.gz
gunzip file.dat.gz
```

Or

```
zcat file.dat
```